# Does Sunlight Sensitivity impose disadvantage from Holy Nimbus?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, racial-traits

Picture this: I'm playing a [kobold](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/kobold), who have the Sunlight Sensitivity trait (Volo's, p. 119)

> You have disadvantage on attack rolls and Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight when you, the target of your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive is in direct sunlight.

Now, I assume from that wording that a normal "bright light" isn't enough - has to be direct sunlight. Except then we get something like [*sunbeam*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam), which not only creates a giant *mah lazor*, it also creates actual sunlight. (PHB, p. 229)

> For the duration, a mote of brilliant radiance shines in your hand. It sheds bright light in a 30-foot radius and dim light for an additional 30 feet. **The light is sunlight.**

So far so good, it sounds like standing next to (or *being*, come to think about it) the caster while he's doing his thing is a bad thing for my eyes.

Except now we come to the [Oath of Devotion paladin](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/paladin#OathofDevotion)'s level 20 feature, Holy Nimbus (PHB, p. 86):

> At 20th level, as an action, you can emanate an aura of sunlight. For 1 minute, bright light shines from you in a 30-foot radius, and dim light shines 30 feet beyond that.

Here, the light is also called sunlight, but it's in the portion of the rules generally reserved for the "fluff" of the rules - is it actally sunlight? Would it hurt my eyes? Is bear-hugging vampires a Devotion Oath paladin sport now?

Comment: There is no "portion of the rules generally reserved for the 'fluff' of the rules".

Comment: Looks like it's time for your Kobold to invest in some shades.

Comment: Directly related [Does holy Nimbus emanate actual sunlight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100363/does-the-holy-nimbus-emanate-actual-sunlight)

Comment: Related: [Is there “flavor text” in D&D 5e spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/78022/28591)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually sunlight.  It says it's sunlight, it's sunlight.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing your perfect 5000 score. :( Though it didn't seem to. Rep-capped for the day, perhaps?

Comment: Ha ha, that's interesting, I didn't know there was a daily cap.

Comment: I recommend adding to this that they're is actually no "fluff" or flavor text to 5e spells as OP seems to think.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose, is that necessarily true?

Comment: @Jack it is actually! According to JC.

Comment: @Jack no where in the text is there mention of fluff or non-mechanical so we must assume that every bit of text is relevant to mechanics. A GM can obviously reflavour abilities (which I recommend as it adds to diversity), but the rules include the whole text.

Comment: There's an actual JC post saying there's no fluff?  Anyone have a link?

Comment: @user26732 [This](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/991012429466251270) is the Tweet generall cited. It is not super explicit, but it doesn't need to be. IT is clear from reading the rules that there is no defined difference between flavor and mechanical text. See also [Is there “flavor text” in D&D 5e spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78012/28591).